# Custom Database

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, datagridview

Do i could make the database like this?

[image]

**Note: One table named `"Database"` with on the left is `"Student Name"` and on the top is `"Month Payment"`, the `CheckBox` is the `CheckBox` in c# winforms.

What I know is I couldn't make the `"Student Name"` on the left corner, the text should be on top like the `"Month Payment".

But, is there a way that i could make my database like the top image and display it on the datagridview and the checkbox is replaced with the checkbox that available in c# winforms, and whenever i open my database (through system), i can check or uncheck the checkbox without have to open the `"(databasename.accdb)"`. Is there a way?

Thank you!

Your answer will be great appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should seperate the thoughts of designing a table with displaying data in a table. Consider such a database design:

A table named paymeht, with columns std_name of varchar, Jan, Feb ... Dec of bool (bit).

I should allow you to modify data using check box for those bool(bit) columns. And, only after fetching data from database in your code, you try to display that data in the way you like.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should name your columns in a non-separate naming like StudentName or Student_Name. I don't know why don't the image appear to me, but you can display it of course on a datagrid with replacing you want.